# How to apply custom filter to a django filters ModelChoicefilter

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm using [Django Filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) to filter data in my Django project.

Now I need to filter some specific `ModelChoiceFilter` based on the current logged in user.

I've tried sending data using `def _init_` to the form and then execute the filtering using `self.fields['field_name'].queryset = my_qs`, but it gives me unresolved error for `self.filters`.

Finally, I've used the [Filter.Method](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method) options from [Django Filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html), here is my code:

**views.py**

```py
    f = RequestsFilter(request.GET,
                       queryset=LeaveRequest.objects.filter(user=request.user),user=request.user.id)
```

**forms.py**

```py
class RequestsFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    start_date = DateFilter(field_name='date_time', lookup_expr='gt', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    end_date = DateFilter(field_name='date_time', lookup_expr='lt', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    employee = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(field_name='employee', method="filter_employee",
                                                queryset=Employee.objects.filter())

    class Meta:
        model = LeaveRequest
        fields = ['employee', 'type', 'date_time']

    def filter_employee(self, queryset, name, value):
        qs = queryset.filter(user=self.user).filter(**{name: value})
        if len(qs) >= 1:
            return qs[0]
        else:
            return None
```

This no longer brings an error, but the `employee` field still shows all of the employees in the database, not filtering it based on the user.

Comment: I have the same problem. And I think it is because the method is not called. Can you test that?